# Why doesn't this chessboard movement work correctly?

Tags: java, chess

I am trying to move a game piece from its initial position to its new position. Note: the move is assumed to be "legal".

```
public void move ( int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
    GamePiece tmp; //Gamepiece is superclass
    tmp=board[fromRow][fromCol];
    board[toRow][toCol]=tmp;
    board[fromRow][fromCol]=new Gamepiece(); //default constructor
    System.out.print(toString()); //this method has the board array printed in correct format
}
```

When I test this, it does not move the correct pieces and doesn't give a blank. Why?

Comment: need more code, like your `GamePiece` class and the `toString()` method, we'll probably also need whatever class `board` is.

Comment: I do not know if this is the case, but from my experience, when dealing with 2D arrays swapping rows and columns usually solved my problems. So it would be like `tmp = board[fromCol][fromRow]`, etc.

Comment: Should a new piece really be made every time something moves? Probably not. This is why `null` exists. Or if you like or need to, have a special instance of `GamePiece` that means no piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing in your code is swapping.  In a regular chess game, you never need to swap. Just replace

```
       tmp=board[fromRow][fromCol];   // don't need this
       board[toRow][toCol]=tmp;  // don't need this
       board[fromRow][fromCol]=new Gamepiece();  // don't need this
```

Just do:

```
       board[toRow][toCol] = board[fromRow][fromCol];
       board[fromRow][fromCol] = null
```

This is all considering your board is a `2D array of ChessPiece`s, for example `ChessPiece[][] board = new ChessPiece[8][8];`

I don't know if this will solve your problem, without seeing more code, but I was just point this out.